# TypeORM MongoDB populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm currently playing around with NestJS and am using MongoDB with TypeORM, and I couldn't find something similar to the `.populate()` method in Mongoose, is there a way to do it with TypeORM or should I stick to Mongoose?

For example, here is a route I created with Express + Mongoose, and I want to recreate it with NestJS + TypeORM:

```js
route.get('/:slug', async (req, res) => {
    const collection = await Collection.findOne({slug: req.params.slug}).populate('products');

    res.json(collection);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `TypeORM` there is something called `relations` which you can use to populate the docs from other(related) collections.

Here is an example from TypeORM docs :

```
createConnection(/*...*/).then(async connection => {
 
    /*...*/
    let photoRepository = connection.getRepository(Photo);
    let photos = await photoRepository.find({ relations: ["metadata"] });
 
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

You can read more about it here on [TypeORM docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm#loading-objects-with-their-relations).

According to how you design collection/schema in TypeORM, your query might look like this, i havent tried the query but you can make it work like this:

```
Collection.find({slug: req.params.slug}, {relations : ['products']});
```

Note, there are also functions like `.innerJoinAndSelect` and `.leftJoinAndSelect` which you can use with `QueryBuilder(.createQueryBuilder)` and populate documents from other collection just like `mongoose .populate()`

I suggest that you read the TypeORM, there are many examples given as well, it will help you build the kind of query you need.

Comment: It seems that adding the `relations` parameter didn't work. Also apparently the `QueryBuilder` methods don't work with MongoDB. I decided to switch back to mongoose, seeing as NestJS has great support for it also.

Comment: For `relations` parameter you needed to update your typeORM schema as well, and define the relation there (like one-to-one or many-to-one), then only it would have worked

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I tried this suggestion of yours and it did not work for me

Comment: @sudo_kaizen The answer here is old, There must be new changes in TypeORM, and i havent used it for like 2 years now, so we need to look for updated solutions. I will see if i get the time to do it, but you can check as well

Comment: I doubt that it ever worked. See this issue [Support Relations in MongoDB](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/655)
Just commenting for anyone who'd like to give it a try. Don't waste your time